# aliasing and time shifting

Tags: dsp-core

I feel like it is a very silly question so I feel ashamed to ask my professor. So i would appreciate it if anybody would help me understand this:

We know that $x(n-a)$ shifts the function $x(n)$ to the right side of $x$ axis by $a$ units.
In aliasing , $x(n+rN)$ is the representation of $x(n)$ shifted to the right by multiples of $N$.

Aren't these two contracting because acc to time shifting $x(n+N)$ should shift the signal by $N$ to the left.

Comment: not for $r < 0$

Comment: We may be able to answer your question if you can reword it into an understandable form. Aliasing is a concept associated with frequency-domain representations, but your question refers to time-domain sequences. Also, know that x(n+rN) is the representation of x(n) shifted to the **left** by multiples of rN samples (shifted left, not right). Can you clarify what "these two contracting" and "acc" mean?

Comment: If $r$ goes from $-\infty$ to $+\infty$, it doesn't matter if you write $x(n+rN)$ or $x(n-rN)$. It usually  helps if you provide the complete context including the formulas, but that would be my guess.